# Screen not registering contact

Tags: android

In MainActivity I have the following method:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i("log_tag","In onTouch");
    Log.i("log_tag", event.getRawX() + " " + event.getRawY());
    return  true;
}
```

Theoretically whenever I click/touch the screen this method should log the location of the contact. Yet whenever I click the screen nothing happens.

The screen is blank, the only thing on the screen is a relative layout that covers the entire screen and is set to "clickable".

How can I get this method to register contact/clicks?

Comment: is your activity implementing OnTouchListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Activity is extending OnTouchListener first, like the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{}
```

The RelativeLayout should have an id set in the XML.

```
android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout"
```

Then put this in the onCreate() of your Activity after setContentView:

```
RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);
layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a view that will received the touch, you can do like that in the MainActivity onCreate():
`findViewById(R.id.main_layout).setOnTouchListener(this);`